# Regex - Unformat XML

Tags: java, regex, xml, indentation

I am trying to unformat a XML to single line. (Using JAVA)

I trying to use following regex to replace.

```
input.replaceAll(">\\s+", ">").replaceAll("\\s+<", "<");
```

However, it also will remove the space in front and behind element.
Which is unexpected.

For example:

Scenario 01

Before: `<AAA>{space}{space}{space}</AAA>`

After: `<AAA></AAA>`

Scenario 02

Before: `<AAA>{space}{space}123{space}{space}</AAA>`

After: `<AAA>123</AAA>`

Scenario 03

Before: `<AAA>{space}A{space}B{space}C{space}</AAA>`

After: `<AAA>A{space}B{space}C</AAA>`

Is there any way to unformat and avoid scenario above?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/18356

Comment: It's not related. OP is asking to reformat XML by replacing line breaks, not parse anything. This is *very* possible with regex.

Comment: Processing XML using regular expressions is always dangerous. Much better to use an XML parser, every time.

Answer (score 1):

A Saxon solution:

```
Processor p = new Processor(false);
DocumentBuilder db = p.newDocumentBuilder();
db.setWhitespaceStrippingPolicy(WhitespaceStrippingPolicy.ALL);
XdmNode doc = db.build(new File(...));
Serializer s = p.newSerializer(new File(...));
s.serialize(doc.asSource());
```

This gives you quite a lot of control over the format of the output by setting properties on the Serializer object.

Answer (score 0):

This will *only* replace *vertical* whitespaces following tag ends and preceding tag starts, e.g. "\n", "\r" or combinations, and others.

```java
input.replaceAll(">\\v+", ">").replaceAll("\\v+<", "<");
```

Excerpt from https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html says:

> `\v` matches “vertical whitespace”, which includes all characters treated as line breaks in the Unicode standard. It is the same as `[\n\cK\f\r\x85\x{2028}\x{2029}]`.